Accessing data of a void pointer without moving pointer
I have a working version of a homemade DNS server/relay written in C and compiled in linux for my router. The process involves encoding/decoding/ammending DNS messages which are accessed via a pointer of type:
void *data

My original version moved this pointer along to access the different data points, however as the code became more complicated, I decided to instead access the data directly without ever moving the pointer to avoid any errors should I forget to return the pointer to its original position. The pointer is thus left to always point to the beginning of the data.
My current version accesses data as follows:
ntohs( *(uint16_t*)&(((char*)data)[pos]) )

to decode the 16bit unsigned integer starting at position pos as an example.
Can this seemingly simple task be done more efficiently/succinctly in C?
Please note that pos should be the number of bytes char from the beginning of the packet.

Define 'move the pointer'.

(char *)data + pos is valid, so you can use ntohs(*(uint16_t)((char*)data + pos)), but uint16_t * u = data; ...; u += ...; ntohs(*u); or ntohs(u[pos/2]) seems a lot cleaner.

The post consists of multiple different questions. (a) For the title question, make a copy of the pointer and use the copy freely, keeping the original value unchanged. (b) For one way to clean up your code, make the copy char * instead of void *, which will reduce the number of casts needed. (c) There is a third question implicitly lurking: *(uint16_t*)&… may violate alignment requirements and may violate aliasing requirements. More information is needed to address that problem.

You can write some helper functions that take a pointer and an offset and return a uint16_t value in network byte order or host byte order. Those helper functions can take care of accessing unaligned data if necessary.

Thank you for your responses. I am using C functions such as recv (https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) and send (https://linux.die.net/man/2/send) which do require void pointers as buffers. I was therefore reluctant to recast data as char although I have not tried it. I also want to avoid uneccessary type conversions, unless required, for code efficiency. To Eric: could you kindly provide some reading material for "alignment requirements" and "aliasing requirements" as I am not familiar with these terms?

Re “do require void pointers as buffers”: No, they do not. You can use any kind of C object you like, including any structure type or an array. When its address is passed to send or recv, the address will automatically be converted to the parameter type, void *. There is absolutely no requirement that the calling routine use void * itself.

Be aware that the C standard does not allow arithmetic on boid pointers, but GCC does.  Be careful if portability is a concern.
